# Proof of "if a physical quantity over subdomains can be superposed, then physical quantity over subdomain is integral over subdomain"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, circles, physics, multiple-integral

Let:

$C$ be a circle

$F$ be some physical quantity over $C$ (eg: force)

$f$ be a function on $C$

$F=\int_C f\ dA$

$P$ be any partition of the circle containing $n$ sub-intervals

$C_i$ be each subinterval

$F_i$ be that physical quantity over $C_i$

Then I need to prove:

> $$F=\sum_{i=1}^{n} F_i$$
>
> implies
>
> $$\forall\ (i\ \leq n) \in \mathbb{N}, F_i=\int_{C_i} f\ dA$$

**My try:**

Since integral can be added and the physical quantity can be superposed:
\begin{align}
F &=\int_C f\\
=
\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}F_i &=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1} \int_{C_i} f \ \text{(for partition $P_1$)}\\
=
\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}F_i &=\sum_{i=1}^{n_2} \int_{C_i} f \ \text{(for partition $P_2$)}\\
=
\sum_{i=1}^{n_3}F_i &=\sum_{i=1}^{n_3} \int_{C_i} f \ \text{(for partition $P_3$)}\\
&\vdots\\
\end{align}

**Now how shall I proceed to show for any partition, for any subinterval,
$$F_i=\int_{C_i} f$$?**

Comment: Why isn't there any response? Is it because nobody gets what I am saying?

Comment: May I please know why isn't there any response... Is it because my question isn't understandable?